# How to shrink the width of div when the elements are removed in resize div

Tags: css, flexbox

Question: I am having two div's A & B where DIV A is having min and max width with resize horizontal feature and Div B is auto width.
Now when Div A has 4 divs in it when each div is removed the width of DIVA is auto shrinked but when i dragg div A to right and remove an element in **DIV A** the width is not auto

```css
.resizeE {
  border-right: 6px solid;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: center;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 150px;
  max-width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
}

.E1 .E2 .E3 .E4 {
  border: 2px solid #A0A0A0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.box {
  width: 30px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}

.red {
  color: red;
  background: pink;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
  background: light-blue;
}

.green {
  color: green;
  background: pink;
}

.map {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:100%;width:100%;background: #e2e2e2;overflow-y: hidden;overflow-x: hidden;">


  <div class="resizeE">
    <div class="red box">E1</div>
    <div class="red box">E2</div>
    <div class="blue box">E3</div>
    <div class="green box">E4</div>
  </div>


  <div class="col p-5">
    <div class="map">
      block B
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

[image: explination of the above code snippet]

Comment: Can you please provide a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). The code that you provide here is not enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @johannchopin here is the JSFiddle to replroduce the problem [link](https://jsfiddle.net/pk1988/15dr9owy/31/)